Avanzar y retroceder una imagen,
Primero saludar a todos ustedes.
Tengo un problema que nadie a podido solucionarme, consulte con la IA y no hubo resultado.
Tengo en html un boton derecha y otro izquierda, pero tengo mas de 4000 imagenes alojadas en mi pc, tengo una opcion para poner "registro", "año" y "numero de hoja" en html, pincho ver imagen y me aparece la pagina que yo elijo, el problema está cuando pincho el botón izquierda o derecha no funciona. Enviare HTML y javascript , si alguno de ustedes me pueda ayudar, de antemano muchas gracias.


function imgActual() {
  var actual = imagenesLight;
  for (i = 0; i < imagenes.length; i++) {
    if (imagenesLight.src === imagenes[i].src)
      break;
  }
  if (i === imagenes.length) i = 0;
  return i
}


document.getElementById('flechaIzq').addEventListener("click", () => {
  let actual = imgActual();
  if (actual > 0) actual--;
  aparecerImagen(imagenes[actual].src);
})


document.getElementById('flechaDer').addEventListener("click", () => {
  let actual = imgActual();
  if (actual < imagenes.length - 1) actual++
    aparecerImagen(imagenes[actual].src);
})
<button id="" flechaIzq "" onclick="" flechaIzq "()"><</button>
<input type="text" id="fojas" name="fojas" size="1" />
<button id="" flechaDer "" onclick="" flechaDer "()">></button>




Decir que no funciona no es suficiente... que has intentado hacer/probar o desarrollar para que funcione ... aparte de que no dejas si hay algun error por consola ...

te recomiendo hacer el [tour]

visualizo la consola y me da errores, los corrijo y me da errores en otra linea y sucesivamente, tambien cambie por este codigo, igual no funciona.

function anteriorImagen() {
currentImagen = (currentImagen - 1 + totalImagenes) % totalImagenes;
console.log("currentImagen:", currentImagen); // Para depurar y verificar si los valores se actualizan.
mostrarImagen();
}

function siguienteImagen() {
 currentImagen = (currentImagen + 1) % totalImagenes;  
  console.log("currentImagen:", currentImagen);
  mostrarImagen();

}


pero es que de eso se trata la programacion... escribes codigo y vas depurando poco a poco... copiar y pegar un codigo y esperar que funcione es incorrecto ... ademas sigues sin decir que es lo que no funciona ... o cual es el error a solucionar

comenzando esto esta mal: id=""flechaIzq"" los tag html van entre un par de comillas dobles, quedaria asi: id="flechaIzq" me pregunto de donde sacaste que debes usar "" al inicio y al final de los tags ...

tienes muchos errores de sintaxis, escritura de codigo html y me imagino que asi mismo esta el javascript ...

esto esta incorrecto: onclick=""flechaIzq"()" debe de ser onclick="flechaIzq()" todavia no me queda claro ... que has intentado ... veo muy poco interes de tu parte en entender que esta mal hecho ...

Debes agregar un [MCVE] donde se aprecie claramente el problema. El código que has puesto está incompleto, faltan funciones y variables que no se saben de donde vienen

Te agradezco Francisco, osea que puedo poner mi proyecto completo para que lo revisen

Ese ejemplo lo saque de esta misma pagina, una respuesta que dio Juan, le vi su perfil y tiene una medalla de oro.

Esta perfecto, que hayas sacado el ejemplo de aca. Pero ese codigo que pusiste, ni siquiera compila. El js, no demuestra tu error porque esta incompleto. Decis que no funciona, pero no podemos saber que cosa no funciona si no vemos lo que no funciona.

Y no, no tenes que subir todoooo tu proyecto, necesitamos un [mcve] que muestre tu problema, para poder decirte que estas haciendo mal...
